# Packing circles with radii 1, 2, 3, ..., n in a rectangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, circle-packing

For each positive integer *n*, let $a_n$ be the area of the smallest rectangle whose area is a whole number, and inside which it is possible to pack all *n* circles of radii 1, 2, 3, ..., *n* respectively (with no overlaps).

Is it possible to determine $a_n$ precisely?

For example $a_{12}$ is at most 2466 (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92949/my-mothers-dish-collection), and can perhaps be proved to be precisely that.

Comment: It's certainly not precisely that. [One of the comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92949/my-mothers-dish-collection#comment266993_92949) links a configuration in a square of area ~2518.16. There has been a lot of work into [packing circles into squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square), with very few bounds actually proven optimal.

Comment: @Wojowu You are right. Have edited accordingly.

Comment: On the same website (last updated in 2015) are [the best known results up to N = 72](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csqn/csqn.html).

Answer (score 14):

Here's a better solution for $n=12$, with area approximately 2496:
[image]

Even better, with area approximately 2463:
[image]

Here's @MattF's suggestion, but it's worse in both dimensions:
[image]

@GerhardPaseman, if I consider only circles 6 through 12, this is the best solution I have found:
[image]

Comment: If you replace 4 by 3, move 12 up and to the left, and then put 4 tangent to 12 and 7, can you cut off some area on the right?

Comment: I added your suggested modification, but I guess the 4 is bigger than it looks.

Comment: Sad. Thanks. Well done on your configuration!

Comment: Suppose you ignore plates one through five temporarily. How small a rectangle do you get for the other seven? (and does it involve a four grouping of 9 12 10 11 with 8 6 7 in a column?) Gerhard "Looking For A Dish Pattern" Paseman, 2020.02.01.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting something slightly different, which would lead to an easy insertion of the remaining disks. However, I am not seeing how to improve the arrangement you provided.  Gerhard "Now Looking For Place Settings" Paseman, 2020.02.01.

Comment: Also, this suggests improving lower bounds by packing the largest plates first. Maybe you can provide some suggestions for those?  Gerhard "Save Bigger Parties For Later" Paseman, 2020.02.01.

Comment: None of my solutions provide lower bounds. This problem is highly nonconvex, and the solver yields optimality proofs only for convex problems.